# Will removing pybootchartgui remove bootchart on 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, software-uninstall, bootchart

I have just installed `pybootchartgui` with:

```
sudo apt-get install pybootchartgui
```

But now after reading [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting) I have realised that as I am running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, `systemd` already has the bootchart capabilities, so I no longer am in need of the package `pybootchartgui` I installed, however, is it safe to remove it or could this cause some problems with the already built-in bootcharting ability?

**Information Update:**

As suggested I have run the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --dry-run pybootchartgui
```

And this was the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  pybootchartgui
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Remv pybootchartgui [0+r141-0ubuntu5]
```

So does this mean that all will be well if I remove the `pybootchartgui` package?

Comment: What does the output say? "`The following packages will be REMOVED`", "`pybootchartgui`", "`0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 0 not to upgrade`". You are not paying me enough to even hint that "all will be well".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do the experiment!

```
sudo apt-get remove --dry-run pybootchartgui
```

will tell you would happen, but makes no change to your system.

However, using logic: Did your system have "some problems" before you installed `pybootchartgui`?

Comment: What kind of problems? I have not tried to use bootchart before if that is what you mean, and I haven't experienced any new problems since installing it, however because after a restart it will start collecting data, this may cause issues due to where the data is stored. Anyway, I have updated my question to include the output of the command you suggested to do the experiment, please take a look and let me know what you think.

Comment: No, I'm asking if the "some problems " you seem to fear existed before you installed `pybootchartgui`. If you noticed problems before, you will probably notice them after. If not, not.

Comment: Right, no there are no problems that I have noticed, I was simply worried that removing `pybootchartgui` could remove something associated with the bootchart in systemd already installed. For instance when removing certain packages, more is removed than would be installed if they were installed again, like if I remove Firefox, certain other packages will be removed, but if I then install Firefox again, I will have to manually install those packages if I wanted them again, and in this case I wouldn’t' know which packages so that was my worry.

Comment: But it seems that the removal will only remove this package and nothing else, so it should not harm any pre-existing bootchating features built-into systemd.